# CentOS 6.10. Как добавить docker-compose в автозапуск

Tags: linux, docker, centos, docker-compose

Есть сервер, который запускается через docker-compose up -d. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузке системы эта команда автоматически запускалась и соответсвенно сервер тоже.

Для этого написал скрипт, который запускается при загрузке системы. В нем команда docker-compose up -d. В ручную скрипт работает и сервер запускается. При запуске системы, другие команды, которые есть в скрипте, например ifconfig отрабатывают, а docker-compose не запускается.

Comment: там ещё нет systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем нашел решение. Сначала вводим команду `crontab -e`.

Затем прописываем:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /path_to_your_project/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 1):

`restart: always` можно писать в `docker-compose.yml`

Это обычно помогает.

Тогда сам `docker-compose` можно будет не запускать повторно.

Comment: Прописано, но не запускаются

Comment: У меня было такое, когда у 2-х контейнеров хитрая общая сеть, можно было только руками в определенном порядке.

Answer (score -1):

Передай управление контейнером в dockerd

```
docker run --restart=always -d your_image
```